# My Password text box shows characters

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, textbox

I use asp.net log in and I want to have some text in my text box as default and after clicking on it, the text box will be clear. I have done it and it works fine. Like picture number 1. But when I use the tab key and go to the password field and typing without any enter, it shows the character like picture number 2!!! it should be stars! or black circles!

for my password text box I used this code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"  
 onclick="this.value=''; this.type='password'; " Width="166px" 
 Font-Size="9pt"  Font-Names="Tahoma">Password                                                    
</asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

Picture number 1

[image]

Picture number 2

any idea for this problem?
Please help me.

Comment: What is the relationship between this question and asp.net-mvc. Please, choose correct tags, when you ask question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

[more info](http://devssolution.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/set-watermark-text-when-textbox-mode-is-password/)

or you can use [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Enter your name"  TextMode="Password"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
TextMode="Password"
```

So it should be:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"  
onclick="this.value=''; this.type='password'; " Width="166px" 
Font-Size="9pt" 
Font-Names="Tahoma">Password                                                    
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks, But when i changed it to the password, the and compile the page. the password text doesn't appear in password text box any more!! any other idea.

Comment: This should definitely work..!! If you are using asp.net framework..There is no other option..@SaeedTalaee

Answer (score 2):

make your password text box type as password:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

and check what you see.

Comment: thanks, But when i changed it to the password, the and compile the page. the password text doesn't appear in password text box any more!! any other idea?